# Azure App Insights REST API Get memory usage

Tags: azure, metrics, performancecounter, azure-application-insights

I want to get host application memory usage and cpu usage by app insights REST API. Can someone tell what are the metrics IDs for these two performance counters, there is confusion in ID names.

Answer (score 0):

using the api explorer tool against demo data:

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY

the metrics in the dropdown appear to be:   `performanceCounters/processPrivateBytes`

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&metricId=performanceCounters%2FprocessPrivateBytes

and `performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage`

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&metricId=performanceCounters%2FprocessCpuPercentage

but it might be specific to what performance counters your app is set up to send.

Answer (score -1):

API:

```
https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2017-05-01-preview
```

In above API you have to pass the resource URI and you will get percentage of CPU

For more info check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/enus/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list#get_metric_for_data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftclassiccomputevirtualmachines